# Sending mail using { System.Net.Mail }

Tags: c#, .net

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Timeout = 10000;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********@gmail.com", "***********");

        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("*********@gmail.com", "******@gmail.com", "delivery.", "tttt");
        mm.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;

            Attachment fMailAttachment;
            fMailAttachment = new Attachment(FilePath);
            mm.Attachments.Add(fMailAttachment);

            client.Send(mm);
            mm.Attachments.Dispose();
```

I am trying to send an email using this code. It works well but only when I am logging in my mail and let it opened, when I close mail it does not send any mails.

what is the problem with that code ?

Comment: What do you mean by "logging in my mail?  You mean logging in to your gmail account or some other mail client?

Comment: Yes, Logging in my Gmail, that one in the code.

Comment: Do you get an exception?  Or error messages of some kind?  I suspect that the authentication is not working properly.

Comment: No, not any error or anything.

Comment: Your code works fine here. Whatever your problem is, it's not in your question.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: I said that it is works fine but only if I am opening my Gmail !!

Comment: So as I said, it's working fine here. Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works well after I edited 
        client.Timeout = 10000; 
To 
        client.Timeout = 100000;